# How to define my function prototype correctly?

Tags: c, function, prototype

My program doesn't work.
My question is how can I define my function prototype correctly? 
Besides, are there any errors in function calling?
Please help me!

Here is my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void copystring(char m[][],char temp[]);
int main()
{
    char temp[10000];
    char m[10000][10000];
    gets(temp);
    copystring(m,temp);
    printf("%s\n",m[0]);
    printf("%s\n",m[1]);            
    return 0;
}

void copystring(char m[][],char temp[])
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k;
    for (k=0;k<(strlen(temp));k++)
    {
        if (temp[k]!=',')
        {
            m[j][i++]=temp[k];
        }
        else
        {
            m[j][i]='\0';
            j++;
            i=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly assume this `char m[10000][10000];` would provoke a stack overflow.

Comment: What is your problem here?

Comment: `void copystring(char m[][10000],char temp[]);` Show full with the exception of the left-most

Answer (score 2):

The quickest "fix" would be to do this:

```
void copystring(char m[][10000],char temp[]);
```

But beware of your 100MB array!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C99 or later change `copystring()`s signature to be:

```
void copystring(size_t n, char m[n][n],char temp[n]);
```

and call it like so:

```
copystring(10000, m, temp);
```

---

Do not use

```
gets(temp)
```

but use

```
fgets(temp, 10000, stdin);
```

The latter takes care of not overflowing `temp`.

Comment: Are there variable length arrays in C?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: Yes, from C99 on there are.